# Hash map and ordered traversal

Tags: c++, iterator, hashmap, abstract-data-type

I am to implement from scratch in C++ a hash map as a full featured abstract data type. Especially, I am to provide an iterator for this data container that would be able to traverse all of the records in an ascending order of the identifying keys. And this part makes me confused, I have no idea how to do this. Btw, by the hashing functionality I decided to use separate chaining with one-direction lists. The one solution that came to me is to make another list that would bind all the elements altogether in an appropriate order, which functionality would be secured during the insertion process itself. But it seems to me that it would impair much of the benefits of hashing itself, at least concerning insertion; especially that looking at my ADT's purpose, the traversal feature will be used relatively seldom. Long story short, what sort of solution should I provide? Please note that I cannot use any specialized libraries.

NOTE:

I know what hash map is and that it is by its academical definition inherently unordered. Maybe I should have put it differently, I am to build a hybrid, practical, ADT that would consist basically of a hash map plus some additional light-weight module that would provide the iterator functionality so that the user of such an ADT could traverse from time to time the records in an ascending order of keys.

Comment: If the traversal won't happen very often, just copy the table in whatever order it's stored and sort it when necessary.

Comment: If this is a proof of concept/school assignment, refer to my answer below. If this is a real-world problem, you need to reconsider your requirement since it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Hilikus Glad to hear that it sounds bizarre, the same was my reaction when I was told to implement that. It is indeed a school assignment.

Comment: I can't think of a way to keep the order in the structure at the same time _and_ keep `insert`s faster than a map.  (And if insert isn't faster than a map, just use a map instead)

Answer (score 3):

Hash maps are inherently unordered.  That's why they are typically named unordered_map in c++.  An iterator for a hash map will visit each member once, but in undefined order.

In practice, you would probably either not use a hash map and use some other associative map container like a red-black tree.  Or you would maintain a parallel ordered index if updates are rare.  Or produce a sorted index on-demand if updates are frequent but traversals are rare.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps are not sorted by nature since the whole point is to use a hash to know where to store the values.

The only way i can see this **might** work (at some cost in performance and real world usability) is if you guarantee that the hash is always increasing, i.e. the hash is a function of the order of insertion and it gives ordered hashes. This will take care of non-colliding hashes only though. You still need to traverse your list within a bucket in the right order, so for that just keep your list sorted at insertion time

Maybe this won't work, it's just an idea

If not, the only other way is to store all the values in a sort-friendly structure and iterate from there. If you do this in the hashmap class it will look like you are iterating the hashmap but you aren't really. Keep in mind that this approach will double your memory requirement at iteration time

Let us know how it goes, this is a bizarre requirement